# How do I place a specific piece of furniture?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

> Zulgar Monomsanreb, Mason has created Rabedëm, a native silver throne!

Great! Put it in the mayor's throne room. No, not that throne, the legendary silver one.

How do I tell the dwarves which piece of furniture to put where, when one item is special?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the menu for placing buildings, where you have the list of buildings by material type you can press <kbd>x</kbd> to be be able to select specific pieces of furniture to place.

Comment: Ack, I don't know how I missed that :p Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't even need to do that, because decorated items and named artifacts are not lumped in with "XXX throne" in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Also note that the placement menu also shows how far away the possible items you can place (your throne, in your example) are from where you are trying to place it.

I often move objects really right next to where I am planning on placing them, and only placing them after that. That way I can select a door in a temporary stockpile two squares away from the doorway where I want it, rather than have my dwarves haul one from a stockpile all the way across the map.